# MemoryHandler not Pushing when application terminates

Tags: java

I am writing a Java Server application using java.util.logging, with a MemoryHandler.

How do I make the MemoryHandler to push data out to file when the application terminates?

I tried to add a ShutDownHook and manually push data to file, but it appears that log handlers already are removed when reaching "hook".

This is my code:

```
public class example implements Runnable{
static {
    // Set upp logging
    // Adding a MemoryHandler
    FileHandler fileHandler = null;
    MemoryHandler memoryHandler;

    try {
        fileHandler = new FileHandler("myapp.log");
        fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    memoryHandler = new MemoryHandler( fileHandler, 100, Level.SEVERE);
    Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
    rootLogger.addHandler(memoryHandler);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Thread serverThread = new Thread(new example());
        serverThread.setDaemon(false);
        serverThread.start();
}

public void run() {

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This is execute when application are shutting down.
            //
            // MemoryHandler are not not in the handlers list
            for (Handler handler: Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers())
            {
                System.out.println("Looping handlers");
                if (handler.getClass() == MemoryHandler.class)
                {
                   System.out.println("Memoryhandler found");
                   //This never happens.
                   ((MemoryHandler)handler).push();
                }

        }
    });

    try {
        // ALOT OF STUFF
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

}
}
```

Please advice!

Comment: The `fileHandler`, `memoryHandler`, and `rootLogger` objects are released as soon as your `static {}` section is executed, since they are all local variables. How are you accessing `memoryHandler` in your shutdown hook?

Comment: @Kenney `Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()` returns once registered handlers